# How do I create fieldSet in my test code?

Tags: unit-testing, salesforce, apex

I'm developing an app on salesforce plateform,now I want to package my app and upload it,but the system tells me I have to test my apex controller at first.In my app,I use fieldSet function:

```
public static List<Schema.FieldSetMember> getDetailed_ContentFields(String typeName,String fieldSetName) {
    List<Schema.FieldSetMember> f = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(typeName)
        .getDescribe().fieldSets.getMap().get(fieldSetName).getFields();
    return f;
}
```

I want to create a fieldset for test but I can not use "Schema.FieldSetMember fieldSet = new Schema.FieldSetMember();"  beacuse Schema.FieldSetMember Type can not be constructed.Can I create fieldset by coding in my test code?Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer no you can't create fieldsets in tests, unless you use the Tooling API.

The fieldset is metadata and can be referenced inside your tests, something like this:

```
@IsTest
static void testGetDetailedContentFields() {
    System.assertEquals(
        MyClassName.getDetailed_ContentFields(MyTypeName, MyFieldSetName),
        Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(MyTypeName).getDescribe().fieldSets.getMap().get(MyFieldSetName).getFields(),
        'Expected the same fieldset to be returned'
    );
}
```